# Assign turtles random positions with no turtles at the same path in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

How to do I assign turtles in Netlogo random positions at start, 
with **no two turtles being assigned the same patch**?
Right now I use the following code but it doesn't give distinct patches for each turtle within limits.

```
 setxy ((random (lengthrec - 1) * 2) - (lengthrec - 1))  ((random (breadth - 2) * 2) - (breadth - 2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is a global `num-turtles` and that this is smaller than the number of patches:

```
to create-turtles
  ask n-of num-turtles patches [sprout 1]
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of it this way.